# I have a mysterious bytecode (executable?) file whose extension is nowhere on the internet. Which SE site should I ask about this in?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Here's what the question would look like:

> I bought a decibel meter off amazon recently ([http://www.amazon.com/Sound-Measure-Tester-Pressure-Decibel/dp/B00CPKSE38/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1436376590&sr=8-1&keywords=wensn](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CPKSE38)) which outputs db measurements to a microsd card. I opened the sd card's content on my computer and encountered four separate *.wsn files, two of which I created and the other two apparently made by the manufacturer in testing perhaps. Anyway, did a google search for the .wsn file extension and can't find anything but something called a "whoopsie skin file" which doesn't appear to be what I'm looking for. Can anyone help me find a way to parse this file? I imagine it simply contains a table of information with two columns (db level and time)
>
> Here's the link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0yWXI3LgLr4ME1DeUs4SDFMX1E/view?usp=sharing

Which site should I ask this on?

Update:
- The db measurement device's manufacturer is "wensn", which clearly accounts for the file name extension. I've found two leads so far:

- [manufacture website for device (not very helpful)](http://www.wensn.com/html_products/digital-Sound-level-meter-WS1361-17.html)
- [reverse engineering wensn usb stream data (pretty advanced stuff)](http://opensource.ebswift.com/RaspiMonitor/wensn/)
- [wensn usb stream github parsing project in python](https://github.com/jeroensteenhuis/wensn)

but both are for parsing usb streams from the device, rather than the static wsn files. I'm guessing I could utilize this code to parse the wsn files, but I don't know how to do that yet.

Comment: I fear there's no SE site for that. Since it's a custom made file by the developers of the product, the product's support forum is the proper place to ask.

Comment: I would like to see the contents of the whoopsie skin file.

Comment: @Won't [WhoopSee Skin File Extension](http://www.file-extensions.org/wsn-file-extension). "*The WhoopSee app seems to be obsolete product without support from developer, or distributor.*" Not quite what you were thinking I imagine...

Comment: Oddly enough, I visited the [manufacturer's website](http://www.wensn.com/) looking for a user's manual there, then it blocked my IP address (it notified me of this in an alert dialog...)

Comment: Including the manufacturer in the text of the question would be helpful.

Comment: @TinyGiant no, the whoopsie skin file extension is not the correct file type. It just shares the same named extension

Comment: @boulder_ruby My comment was a response to the comment by Won't.

Comment: @TinyGiant that site is dead, and [not only for you](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://www.wensn.com/) (no IP ban, just a regular crash of a site)

Comment: Anyway, that website is BAD - e.g. see [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150517233653/http://www.wensn.com/) - hacked, and if archived this way it means it stayed hacked for long days, even weeks. I would have really stayed away from such company.

Answer (score 6):

If you would include an extract from the file (probably in a hex format), you could try to ask this on [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/). You should then clearly explain *what the file looks like* (by giving an example / extract) and *what that data represents*.

Comment: question posted here: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9309/mysterious-bytecode-executable-file-from-a-chinese-decibel-meter-whose-manufa. Thanks for the tip, we'll see what happens!

Comment: It's doing well so far so +1